# Convert base64 png to jpeg image in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, fabricjs, node-canvas

I am using **FabricJS** module in **Nodejs**. There is a Canvas I am trying to export as `jpeg` but it wont(giving me a hard time). All I am getting is **base64 png** data.

Data that starts like

```
data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAfQAAAH0CAYAAADL1t.....
```

Is there anyway in nodejs that I can convert this image to jpeg? I googled a lot but couldn get a solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [png-to-jpeg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/png-to-jpeg) module. Assuming the 'data' is in string form :

```
const fs = require("fs");

const pngToJpeg = require('png-to-jpeg');
const imgStr = 'data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAfQAAAH0CAYAAADL1t.....';

const buffer = new Buffer(imgStr.split(/,\s*/)[1],'base64');
pngToJpeg({quality: 90})(buffer).then(output => fs.writeFileSync("./some-file.jpeg", output));
```

Answer (score -6):

Ok, because I'm a professional Googler (just kiding ), I found something for you, firstly, you'll have to install [ATOB for NodeJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/atob), now, just use it to decode the base64 string, like this :

```
(function () {
  "use strict";

  var atob = require('atob');
  var b64 = ; //your base64 string
  var bin = atob(b64);
  var fs = require('fs');
  fs.writeFile("./test.jpg", bin, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

      console.log("The file was saved!");
   }); 
}());
```

Actually, I'm not using NodeJS, so I can't tell you more than that, I hope that it will solve your problem!

Comment: That's a polyfill for the native atob function that's used to convert a base64 string to binary, which does not solve the problem OP was asking.